# Null pointer exception while implementing Heapify for removing minimum value in MinHeap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, heap

For the below program:

```
public class MinHeap<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
implements HeapInterface<T> {

private T[] backingArray;
private int size;
// Do not add any more instance variables

/**
 * Creates a Heap.
 */
public MinHeap() {
    backingArray = (T[]) new Comparable[STARTING_SIZE];
    size = 0;
}

@Override
public void add(T item) {
    if (item == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item was null.");
    }
    if (size + 1 >= backingArray.length) {
        resize();
    }
    backingArray[size + 1] = item;
    int i = size + 1;
    while (i > 1 && backingArray[i].compareTo(backingArray[i / 2]) <= 0) {
        swap(backingArray[i], backingArray[i / 2], i, i / 2);
        i = i / 2;
    }
    size++;
}

private void resize() {
    T[] backingArrayTemp = backingArray;
    backingArray = (T[]) new Comparable[backingArrayTemp.length * 2];
    for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++) {
        backingArray[i] = backingArrayTemp[i];
    }
}

private void swap(T item1, T item2, int i, int parent) {
   backingArray[parent] = item1;
   backingArray[i] = item2;
}
@Override
public T remove() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Heap is empty.");
    }
    T temp = backingArray[1];
    backingArray[1] = backingArray[size + 1];
    size--;
    heapify(1);
    return temp;
}

private void heapify(int i) {
    int left = 2*i;
    int right = 2*i + 1;
    int min = i;
    if (left < size && backingArray[left].compareTo(backingArray[min])
            < 0) {
        min = left;
    }
    if (right < size
            && backingArray[right].compareTo(backingArray[min]) < 0) {
        min = right;
    }
    if (min != i) {
        swap(backingArray[i], backingArray[min], i, min);
        heapify(min);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    size = 0;
    backingArray = (T[]) new Comparable[STARTING_SIZE];
}
```

We start indexing at i = 1. 
My add method works fine, and I've tried changing from `backingArray[1] = backingArray[size + 1];` to `backingArray[1] = backingArray[size]` 
in the remove method, but that doesn't seem right and also didn't work. It got rid of the null pointer but didn't pass all my tests. I'm getting null pointers at

```
backingArray[left].compareTo(backingArray[min]) < 0)
```

because `backingArray[min]` is null.

**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:1216)
at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:52)
at MinHeap.heapify(MinHeap.java:68)
at MinHeap.remove(MinHeap.java:60)
```

Comment: Please provide stacktrace.

Comment: Just added the trace.

Comment: You always use `i = 1`, however the first element's index is `0` - can that be it?

Comment: No the first element is supposed to be at 1. It's the way we're implementing it. It's a small detail.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of `heapify()`, and specifically, the `heapify(1)` in `remove()`?

Comment: It restores the heap property. I just realized I should change backingArray[size + 1] to backingArray[size] but there are still some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test this, right now, but I think the main problem is in the `resize()` method. When you create the temporary array to hold the data

```
T[] backingArrayTemp = backingArray;
```

you actually tell the new array to point to the same address in the memory as the original backingArray. Then you reallocate `backingArray` and also the temp array, since they point to the same place in memory. Then, of course, all the elements will not be initialized and the bеhaviour will not be as expected.

The correct way to do this is to create a "new" array and then copy the values:

```
T[] backingArrayTemp = new T[backingArray.length];
for(int i = 0; i < backingArray.length; ++i)
    backingArrayTemp[i] = new T(backingArray[i]);
```

Where each element is copied with a constructor to avoid similar issues.

About `heapify()` - I don't know how exactly you will use that min heap, but I guess you will always put the elements one at a time. If you ever need to create the heap from a random array you will need a more complex routine that goes through the entire heap. I can provide you with some more information, if interested.

Comment: I'm adding elements one at a time. I'm sure something is wrong with the heapify method. My tests for resize work, but I'm mainly concerned with heapify.

Comment: Ok then. Why in the remove() method you use "size + 1" in the following line:
backingArray[1] = backingArray[size + 1];
Shouldn't it be size - 1?

Comment: That was because we started the array indices at 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I didn't set backingArray[size] = null.